# JW Player controls are squashed in Safari and Chrome when in a DIV that slides down

Tags: jquery, slide, jwplayer

I am using the Wordpress JW Player plugin, and the JW player is in a DIV that slides down on page load. In Safari and Chrome the controls are squashed on the left when the player first loads. After a couple of seconds the controls disappear and then only reappear if hovering over the player, by which time they are centred, in the correct place. I am not seeing this behaviour in Firefox.  You can see what I mean on this page:

http://opendialogueapproach.co.uk

I am wondering what I can do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a clash between our html5 player's css and your site/theme's css. I would see if setting the default rendering mode to flash in the plugin settings helps resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the default rendering mode to flash, and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: When I check your link out it is still running in html5 mode.

Comment: Sorry, it is in flash mode now.  What I am now seeing in Safari and Firefox is that the whole video needs to load before playback starts. Is this the expected behaviour with flash?

Comment: The squashed controls aren't seen in flash mode though, so that would fit with your theory that there is a clash with my theme's CSS. Another issue I have noticed is that it appears that Firefox is using Flash mode even when the default is set to html5. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: I would try to do a basic embed first with the css removed and then add it back to see where it breaks.